# how to add css cards(eg pricing cards) into a carousel

Tags: html, css

i have about 6 css pricing cards/tables i modified, the tables are arranged normally  but instead of the tables coming down to the next line after first row is full, i want it inside a carousel, that scrolls left or right continuously, even after reaching the end, it should start from the 
beginning again

what i have at the moment [image]

the html(i only have 3 cards in my html as i didnt want to make the code bulky, though its meant to be six)

```
  <div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color" style="background-color: rgb(157, 149, 149);"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header style="padding:30px; background-color: gray;color: white;">
            <h2 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;">4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3 style="font-size: 14px;opacity: 0.6"><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
                                        <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>1</dd>
                                        <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>4</dd>
                                        <dt>Area</dt>
                                        <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
                                        <dt>Garages</dt>
                                        <dd>1</dd>
                                    </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div> 

<div class="columns item">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/2.jpg" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color" style="background-color: rgb(157, 149, 149);"><span>₦75 MILLION</span></div>
        <header style="padding:30px; background-color: gray;color: white;">
            <h2 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500">4 Bedroom Terrace</h2>
            <h3 style="font-size: 14px;opacity: 0.6"><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>  Ikate Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
                                        <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>1</dd>
                                        <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>4</dd>
                                        <dt>Area</dt>
                                        <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
                                        <dt>Garages</dt>
                                        <dd>3</dd>
                                    </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/3.jpg" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color" style="background-color: rgb(157, 149, 149);"><span>₦100 MILLION</span></div>
        <header style="padding:30px; background-color: gray;color: white;">
            <h2 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500">5 Bedroom Detached House</h2>
            <h3 style="font-size: 14px;opacity: 0.6"><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Lekki County Home </h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
                                        <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>1</dd>
                                        <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
                                        <dd>5</dd>
                                        <dt>Area</dt>
                                        <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
                                        <dt>Garages</dt>
                                        <dd>1</dd>
                                    </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>
   </div>
```

and the css

```
   * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
            }          

.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.house {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
}

.house:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.house .header {

    color: white;

}

.house li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.house .grey {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.item dl {
     color: #919191; 
     font-size: 12px; 
     padding: 30px; 
}

dl {
     margin-bottom: 0; 
}

dl {
     margin-top: 0; 
     margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.item dl dd {
   text-align: right; 
     margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

dl dd {
     text-align: right; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.item dl dt {
     float: left; 
    font-weight: normal;
}

dl dt {
     float: left; 
}
.price {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

    background-color: #626262;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.price:after {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.price span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.average-color {
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
     -webkit-transition: 0.4s; 
    transition: 0.4s; 
}
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve your problem without javascript. So I created a small script for you: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Glubey/mLpwxxLy/) *(I used jQuery)*. But if you want to make a better and more user-friendly carousel, you should add events and buttons.

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div id="container"> <!-- contains the items -->

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="columns item" >
    <a href="#">
  <ul class="house">
    <div class="header"><img src="img/houses/4.jpg" alt="img" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="price average-color"><span>₦60 MILLION</span></div>
        <header>
            <h2>4 Bedroom Terrace Houses</h2>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i> Romay Gardens Estate, Lekki</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <dl>
               <dt>Bathrooms</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               <dt>Bedrooms</dt>
               <dd>4</dd>
               <dt>Area</dt>
               <dd>165m<sup>2</sup></dd>
               <dt>Garages</dt>
               <dd>1</dd>
               </dl>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </ul>
    </a>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
/* class house */
.house {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.house:hover { box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
.house {color: #fff;}
.house footer {color: #000;}
.house li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
header {padding:30px; background-color: gray;color: white;}
h2 {font-size: 18px; font-weight: 500;}
h3 {font-size: 14px;opacity: 0.6}
a {text-decoration: none;}
img {display: block; height: 150px;}
.price {background-color: rgb(157, 149, 149);}

/* NEW or EDITED */

#container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; /* no wrap */
}
.columns {
    display: inline-block; /* arrange colums next to each other */
    width: 25%;
    padding: 8px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**JS:**

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    $(function() {
    function slide() {
        $(".item").first().animate({        // animate margin of first item
            marginLeft: "-25%"             // 25% is the width of one item
        }, 4000, "linear", function() {    // callback
            $("#container").append(this);  // change order
          $(this).css("margin-left", 0);   // set margin to 0
          slide();                         // loop
        });
        }
    slide();                               // invocation
  });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```